# srings manipulation : Regex Replace with \ T

Tags: c#

I have this line :

```
return Regex.Replace(pPath, $@"\\\\{server.Name}\\", $@"\\{{{server.Alias}}}\", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

throwing a System.ArgumentException :

> unable to analyse the escape sequence \T. path :
>   \filerrect**\T**I\GDF\ReceptionFlux\bancaire\PEEXPJ010\20200220\PEEXPJ010_P1ADP_2ADP2_XXXXXX_PAYER_FSS_VIR_BBRED_FS_0027010_20200127_202732.tmp $@"\{{{server.Alias}}}\" = "\\{GDFEntrant}\"
>   $@"\\{server.Name}\"=
>   "\\\\filerrect\TI\GDF\ReceptionFlux\\"

The problem i think is to interpret \TI as it is a part og the path name.
How to deal with this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure you need regular expressions at all here, rather than `string.Replace`? It's very unclear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please put your code in code blocks (3 backticks ` )

Comment: I think it's because A backslash \ in a regular expression is used to escape character. Maybe you need to double your backslash. The regex escape come in addition to the string escape so even if you put a @ at the beginning you need to double your backslash for the regex itself.

Answer (score 5):

When composing patterns dynamically, use Regex.Escape method to be sure not to include some invalid regular expression escape sequence.
Your code should look like:

```
return Regex.Replace(pPath, Regex.Escape($@"\\{server.Name}\"), $@"\\{{{server.Alias}}}\", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```